# Can I move a vertex in MeshLab?

Tags: meshlab

I know how to select and delete individual vertices in MeshLab.

Can I move an individual vertex? That would be helpful for minor cleanup of my human photogrammetry meshes. I know I can do it in Blender, but I'd prefer to do as much as possible in MeshLab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is:
"No, You can't move individual vertex. Meshlab is a mesh processor, not an editor, so it is not possible to move one vertex in a interactive way as in Blender or Maya, using the mouse to drag the vertices."

Despite that, the truth is that you can move one vertex or a selection of vertices using this emergency trick.

1. Select one or several vertex in your mesh:
   [image]
2. Apply the 'Per vertex Geometric Function' filter. Check the 'only on selection' and the 'Preview' options. and create a formula that does the change to your vertex coordinates.
   [image]

Comment: Thank you. That will work.   :)    TS